# what am I doing wrong in JS? i need one coord to each element but not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

ajax and xml parser

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=43.2491,76.9198&sco=latlong&kind=house&results=7',//here get the XML wirh all adresses and coords
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(d){
        $("#message").html('');
        var coord = $(d).find('pos').text();
        $(d).find('name').each(function(){
            $('#message').prepend("<div class='addresses' onClick='insert_adress($(this).text());'>"+$(this).text()+" и "+coord+"</div>"); //here it write to a box                
        })
    }
});
```

[here is example oj jssfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHJ6S/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this  http://jsfiddle.net/cHJ6S/3/

```
...
            $(d).find('GeoObject').each(function () {
              var coord = $(this).find('pos').text();
              var name =  $(this).find('name').text();
              $('#message').prepend("<div class='addresses' onClick='insert_adress($(this).text());'>"+name+" и "+coord+"</div>"); 
            });
...
```

Is this the result you wnat?

```
улица Муратбаева, 183 и 76.918695 43.249010
улица Муратбаева, 185 и 76.919100 43.248557
улица Муратбаева, 168 и 76.919692 43.248426
улица Карасай батыра, 108 и 76.920294 43.249496
улица Шагабутдинова, 103а и 76.920375 43.248991
улица Муратбаева, 166 и 76.919989 43.248761
улица Муратбаева, 164 и 76.919684 43.249214
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to convert xml into json using php, and then send it to js.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked the **console**, you would have seen the following error

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Object 76.919800 43.24910076.919684
>   43.24921476.919989 43.24876176.920375 43.24899176.920294 43.24949676.919692 43.24842676.919100 43.24855776.918695 43.249010 has no method 'next'

This line is the cause of your problem.

```
var coord = $(d).find('pos').text().next();  //remove next will fix it
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/cHJ6S/2/)

**FYI:** Press F12, to check console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(d).find('name'),`

use `$(d).find('featuremember').each(function(){...}),`

featuremember - represents object, so why not loop through objects

then use inside loop

```
var pos = $($(this).find('pos')).text();
var name = $($(this).find('name')).text();
```

finally

```
$('someId').prepend(name + ' pos: ' + pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var coord = $(d).find('pos').text();
```

**Full code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=43.2491,76.9198&sco=latlong&kind=house&results=7',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(d){
        $("#message").html('');
        var coord = $(d).find('pos').text();// pos text not its next element's text
        $(d).find('name').each(function(){
            $('#message').prepend("<div class='addresses' onClick='insert_adress($(this).text());'>"+$(this).text()+" и "+coord+"</div>");                 
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHJ6S/4/)